# How can I go back to the start of while loop, without breaking it?

Tags: java, path-finding

I have a while loop containing many if's:

```
public ArrayList<Position> findPath(Position destination) {
        boolean pathToDestinationCreated = false;
        boolean xReached = false;
        boolean yReached = false;
        int reachableX = 0;
        int reachableY = 0;
        int reachableXY = 0;

        int isUnreachable = 0;
        Position myPos = myPlayer().getPosition();
        ArrayList<Position> finalPath = new ArrayList<Position>();
        if (destination != null) {
            Position toAdd;
            while (!pathToDestinationCreated) {
                if (myPos.getX() != destination.getX() && myPos.getY() != destination.getY()) {
                    if (myPos.getX() < destination.getX() && myPos.getY() < destination.getY()) {
                        toAdd = new Position(myPos.getX() + 1, myPos.getY() + 1, myPos.getZ());
                        if (canReach(toAdd)) {
                            finalPath.add(toAdd);
                            myPos = toAdd;
                            isUnreachable = 0;
                        } else {
                            isUnreachable = 1;
                        }
                    } else if (myPos.getX() > destination.getX() && myPos.getY() < destination.getY()) {
                        toAdd = new Position(myPos.getX() - 1, myPos.getY() + 1, myPos.getZ());
                        if (canReach(toAdd)) {
                            finalPath.add(toAdd);
                            myPos = toAdd;
                            isUnreachable = 0;
                        } else {
                            isUnreachable = 1;
                        }
                    } else if (myPos.getX() > destination.getX() && myPos.getY() > destination.getY()) {
                        toAdd = new Position(myPos.getX() - 1, myPos.getY() - 1, myPos.getZ());
                        if (canReach(toAdd)) {
                            finalPath.add(toAdd);
                            myPos = toAdd;
                            isUnreachable = 0;
                        } else {
                            isUnreachable = 1;
                        }
                    } else if (myPos.getX() < destination.getX() && myPos.getY() > destination.getY()) {
                        toAdd = new Position(myPos.getX() + 1, myPos.getY() - 1, myPos.getZ());
                        if (canReach(toAdd)) {
                            finalPath.add(toAdd);
                            myPos = toAdd;
                            isUnreachable = 0;
                        } else {
                            isUnreachable = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I'm gonna skip the rest of the code because a wall of text isn't going to help.

I'd like to go back to the beginning of my while loop, whenever finalPath.add(toAdd) is invoked. How would I do this?

Comment: have you looked at the `continue` keyword? But having said that, this code looks to be at risk of degenerating into spaghetti code. Consider refactoring, creating some methods perhaps, to allow for some much needed simplification.

Comment: I'm afraid it already is spaghetti-code. I'll definitely have to refactor this and think of some changes to make this look better. Continue seems to be what I was searching for though, I had no idea it does this, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want recursion?

Comment: I am pretty sure I don't want recursion. When I enter the while loop, I have to create the whole path before I leave it.

Comment: @BlackDynamite: properly used, recursion could do this, create your whole path, but you risk running out of memory.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Could you perhaps link me to any "methods" on how to prevent writing code that is spaghetti/confusing like I have here? I mean the only way I currently know is creating another methods that would have to take as parameters some variables from my function

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Perhaps it is do-able with recursion, but I "pretty new" to programming, and I don't think my strength level is high enough to write a recursive function for finding a path. I don't even know any path-finding algorithm, I just try to write a working one XD

Comment: I agree that continue is the answer to your question, and disagree that recursion is any kind of help.  Look at the code for things that are repeated, and use simple constructs to avoid repeating them.  Put results of `pos.getX()` & `destination.getX()` into variables, and test the variables; don't keep making the calls.  you can put all of the logic for the `if(canReach(toAdd))` loop into one function and call it.  When the loop is short it is a lot easier to follow.

Comment: @rcook Yes, I've done everything you said, except for "you can put all of the logic for the if(canReach(toAdd)) loop into one function and call it", I've tried doing this, but it appears I can't do continue; afterwards. :/

Comment: Why doesn't it already go back to the beginning of your loop?  What other code is it executing?  Anyway, although `continue` will go back to the beginning of the loop, in my opinion it makes spaghetti code even worse and should usually be avoided.  If there's additional code in the `while` loop that you don't want to execute under certain conditions, put it inside an `if` so that it's clear that it won't be executed in those conditions.

Comment: ajb, it might happen that more than one case is true in that while loop. In that case, it would add more than one position in one going-through while loop. I want to avoid that, due to that fact that the FIRST if's in the while loop are the most optimal ones (diagonal).

Comment: PS. I have finished the code, and thanks to you guys it works awesome! look at the pic to see it in action: [link](http://i.imgur.com/GLf1NmQ.png?1)

Comment: What it does -> finds the most optimal path, starting from my position to the destination, and if possible, walks there. If it's not possible, based on my current position, it searches for any obstacles (obstacles are searched based on the furtest-available tile) and handles them.

Comment: @BlackDynamite You're using `else` on all your `if`s, so I don't see how it could be doing more than one thing.

Comment: @ajb this is not everything :) Code is 3x longer.